# How to create 2 multidimensional string array (remove blank strings)?

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array

```
var movieNext = new string[,]
{
    { "superhero", "action", "waltdisney", "bat"}, 
    {"superhero", "action", "marvel",""}, 
    {"history", "action", "malay", "" },
    {"malay", "novel", "", ""}, 
    {"history", "bat", "", ""}
};
```

The above code is a multidimensional array, which stores a sequence of movie's keyword. Is there a way to implement this without having to put the blank strings in the array initialization?

For example you can see in the above code, I have to put the blank string "" to fill up the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider C# jagged array (though they are different from multi-dimensional arrays).

```
string[][] movieNext =  {
new [] { "superhero", "action", "waltdisney", "bat"},
new []  {"superhero", "action", "marvel"}, <and so on>
};
```

If you want to stick with multi-dimensional arrays, you have to initialize the values individually. If you don't provide any string value for any of the index (i,j) by default it will be null.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) instead.

```
string[][] movieNext = new string[][] { { etc... } }.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest never to use two-dimensional arrays. They have practically no support in the API (you'll be hard pressed to find a method that accepts a two-dimensional array as a parameter), and cannot be cast to `IEnumerable<T>` or similar well-supported interface. As such, you can really use them only in the most local of scopes.

Instead, I suggest you use something castable to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`. Oh, another tip. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx) out. Specifically,

> To initialize a Dictionary, or any collection whose Add method takes multiple parameters, enclose each set of parameters in braces as shown in the following example.

Thus, the following will work:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new ManyList()
        {
            {"Hi", "Good", "People", "None", "Other"}
            {"Maybe", "Someone", "Else", "Whatever"}
        };
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class ManyList : List<string>
{
    public void Add(params string[] strs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strs));
    }
}
```

This might help you clean up your syntax a bit.